# Why Vue.js text editors print all html tags and inline styles?

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor, froala

On my Vue.js application i have tried CKEditor, tiptap, Froala etc. and every one of them prints out all html tags and all inline css styles.
Some images for better understanding what is a problem:

[image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBSWw.jpg)

[image with described problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfuaV.jpg)

[blog form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTuFP.jpg)

I have searched web and found verly little info about this so if anyone know why is this happening please help me out :)

Kind Regards,
Sinisa

Comment: If you don't want formatting of your text then just use a `<textarea>` instead. If you do want formatting then it's unclear where the confusion lies.

Comment: Yes i do want formatting, i want to have ability for blog creators to add some styles and what not to their content.

Answer (score 2):

you should use v-html and put your text variable inside the element like this:

```
<p v-html="yourTextVariable"></p>
```

---

by the way if you use v-html u probably need to make text appear on next line instead of overflowing (overflowing text is common issue that happen when u use v-html) :

```
p{
    color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: justify;
    white-space: initial;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```